# Empty setter vs no setter in properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties

What is the difference between this two property implementations?

```
public override string A
{
    get { return "s"; }
    set { }
}

public override string A
{
    get { return "s"; }
}
```

Comment: Try `A = "";` and see what happens.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, since `A` is `override` than the base class must have *both* `get` and `set` (otherwise the code doesn't compile) e.g.

```
public class MyBase {
  public virtual String A {
    get {
      return "getBaseA";
    }
    set {
      throw new NotSupportedException("setBaseA");
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have two different derived classes:

```
public class MyDerivedA: MyBase {
  public override String A {
    get {
      return "s";
    }
    set { // set is overridden, now set does nothing
    }
  }
}

public class MyDerivedB: MyBase {
  public override String A {
    get {
      return "s";
    }
    // set is not overridden, same as in the base class
  }
}
```

Let's call both `set` methods:

```
// Does nothing: overridden MyDerivedA.A.set is called
MyBase test1 = new MyDerivedA();
test1.A = "Sample";

// Will throw NotSupportedException (base MyBase.A.set is called)
MyBase test2 = new MyDerivedB();
test2.A = "Sample";
```

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Thank you for hint! `NotSupportedException` is actually a better choice.

Answer (score 7):

The first one will override the setter for `A` in base class with a method which is doing nothing. So you can have `A = ""` but it is doing nothing.

The method when you define a setter will be `public override TheCompilerGeneratedNameForSetterOfAInBaseClass(string value) { }` and in the second case `A = ""` will compile but it will call the base class setter for `A`.

Answer (score 4):

This getter and setter is **overriden**.
This code would compile in both cases when doing `x.A =""`.
In the first case we override set property which means when you try to assign a value to the object nothing will happen. In the second case it will use base class implementation

Answer (score 2):

You use `override`, so I assume the class your fragment is from has a baseclass with something like

```
public virtual string A { get; set; }
```

If you just override the getter (your second example), the original setter will still be used. You just don't see the result as it is hidden by your override.

When you also override the setter with an empty method, the base setter will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

First: there is a setter, but in that setter will do nothing
Second: there is no setter

Comment: Sure there is, but it's easy to miss. There's a setter in both cases. In the first case the base class setter is overridden (to do nothing), while in the second case the base class setter is inherited (to do whatever it is implemented to do).